# Powershell: capturing remote output streams in Invoke-Command + Invoke-Expression combination

Tags: powershell, remoting

As I didn't find a solution by searching the forum and spent some time for finding out how to do it properly, I'm placing here the issue along with the working solution.

Scenario: in Powershell, need to remotely execute a script block stored in a variable and capture its output for further processing. No output should appear on the screen unless the script generates it on purpose. The script block can contain Write-Warning commands.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the **behaviors of interest apply *generally* to PowerShell commands**, not just in the context of `Invoke-Command` and the - [generally to be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/) - `Invoke-Expression`; in your case, it is only needed to work around a *bug*.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

Your [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60565721/45375) shows how to **redirect a single, *specific* output streams to the success output stream**; e.g, **`3>&1`** redirects (`>&`) the *warning* stream (`3`) to the *success (output) stream* (`1`).

<sup>The `&` indicates that the redirection target is a *stream*, as opposed to a *file*; for more information about PowerShell's output stream, see [`about_Redirection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection).</sup>

If you want to **redirect *all* output streams to the success output stream, use redirection `*>&1`**

By redirecting all streams to the output stream, their **combined output can be captured in a variable, redirected to a *file*, or sent through the pipeline**, whereas by default only the *success* output stream (`1`) is captured.

*Separately*, you can **use the [common parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters) named `-*Variable` parameters to capture individual stream output *in variables*** for *some* streams, namely:

- Stream `1` (success): `-OutVariable`
- Stream `2` (error): `-ErrorVariable`
- Stream `3` (warning): `-WarningVariable`
- Stream `6` (information): `-InformationVariable`

<sup>Be sure to specify the target variable by *name* only, *without the `$` prefix*; e.g., to capture warnings in variable `$warnings`, use

`-WarningVariable warnings`, such as in the following example:

`Write-Warning hi -WarningVariable warnings; "warnings: $warnings"`</sup>

Note that **with `-*Variable`, the stream output is collected in the variable *whether or not you silence or even ignore that stream otherwise***, with the **notable exception of `-ErrorAction Ignore`**, in which case an `-ErrorVariable` variable is *not* populated (and the error is also *not* recorded in the [automatic `$Error` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#error) that otherwise records all errors that occur in the session).

Generally, **`-{StreamName}Action SilentlyIgnore`** seems to be **equivalent to `{StreamNumber}>$null`**.

---

Note the **absence of the verbose (`4`) and the debug (`5`)** streams above; you **can only capture them *indirectly*, via `4>&1` and `5>&1`** (or `*>&1`), which then requires you to extract the output of interest from the *combined* stream, via filtering by output-object *type*:

**Important**:

- The **verbose (`4`) and debug (`5`) streams** are the only two streams that are **silent *at the source* by default**; that is, **unless these streams are explicitly turned on** via `-Verbose` / `-Debug` or their [preference-variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables) equivalents, `$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'` / `$DebugPreference = 'Continue'`, **nothing is emitted and nothing can be captured**.
- The **information stream (`5`)** is **silent only *on output* by default**; that is, writing to the information stream (with `Write-Information`) *always* writes objects to the stream, but they're not *displayed* by default (they're only displayed with `-InformationAction Continue` / `$InformationPreference = 'Continue'`)

  - Since v5, `Write-Host` now too writes to the information stream, though *its* output *does* print by default, but can be suppressed with `6>$null` or `-InformationAction Ignore` (but *not* `-InformationAction SilentlyContinue`).

```
# Sample function that produces success and verbose output.
# Note that -Verbose is required for the message to actually be emitted.
function foo { Write-Output 1; Write-Verbose -Verbose 4 }

# Get combined output, via 4>&1
$combinedOut = foo 4>&1

# Extract the verbose-stream output records (objects).
# For the debug output stream (5), the object type is
# [System.Management.Automation.DebugRecord]
$verboseOut = $combinedOut.Where({ $_ -is [System.Management.Automation.VerboseRecord] })
```

---

[1] **Stream-capturing bug, as of PowerShell v7.0:**

In a nutshell: **In the context of *remoting* (such as `Invoke-Command -Session` here), *background jobs*, and so-called *minishells* (passing a script block to the PowerShell CLI to execute commands in a child process), only the success (`1`) and error (`2`) streams can be captured as expected**; all other are unexpectedly passed through to the host (display) - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9585).

Your command *should* - but currently doesn't - work as follows, which would obviate the need for `Invoke-Expression`:

```
# !! 3>&1 redirection is BROKEN as of PowerShell 7.0, if *remoting* is involved
# !! (parameters -Session or -ComputerName).
$RemoteOutput = 
  Invoke-Command -Session $Session $Commands 3>&1 -ErrorVariable RemoteError 2>$null
```

That is, in principle you should be able to pass a `$Commands` variable that contains a script block directly as the (implied) `-ScriptBlock` argument to `Invoke-Command`.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation but, as you mentioned itself, my post is related to resolving only this specific situation where remote output of Invoke-Expression can't be captured as expected.

Regarding your comment "generally to be avoided - Invoke-Expression". I'm aware about that but it seems to be an overstatement. I know the reason behind that recommendation but I don't consider it to be too important. In the end, correctness of your code is a matter of testing in any case.

Comment: In case you're interested in the global task, it's about mass-executing a code block from an external file. The content of the file is not known in advance. Executing the commands directly by using the parameter of Invoke-Command doesn't allow to capture remote output properly and sometimes simply doesn't work throwing remote execution errors.

Comment: Thanks, @Evgeny. Yes, the direct capturing of streams from a remote invocation is buggy, as the footnote hopefully makes clear; I'm not aware of other errors, so I can't speak to your statement about throwing remote execution errors.

Comment: As for warning against `Invoke-Expression` use being an overstatement: It is the sensible  [recommendation by a core member of the PowerShell team](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/) and there is an [ongoing discussion on how to best frame this recommendation in the official documentation](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11662). Note the word _generally_: the point is that while there may be legitimate uses (certainly, your workaround for the stream-capturing bug is one), there are _typically better and safer_ solutions

Answer (score 0):

Script block is contained in `$Commands` variable. `$Session` is an already established Powershell remoting session.

The task is resolved by the below command:

```
$RemoteOutput = 
  Invoke-Command -Session $Session {
    Invoke-Expression $Using:Commands 3>&1
  } -ErrorVariable RemoteError 2>$null
```

After the command is executed all output of the script block is contained in `$RemoteOutput`. Errors generated during remote code execution are placed in `$RemoteError`.

Additional clarifications. `Write-Warning` in `Invoke-Expression` code block generates its own output stream that is not captured by `Invoke-Command`. The only way to capture it in a variable is to redirect that stream to the standard stream of `Invoke-Expression` by using `3>&1`. Commands in the code block writing to other output streams (verbose, debug) seems not to be captured even by adding `4>&1` and `5>&1` parameters to `Invoke-Expression`. However, stream #2 (errors) is properly captured by `Invoke-Command` in the way shown above.